# Screen snapshot Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, screenshot

I have the following Xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Take a picture" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
        <Grid x:Name="MainPageBluePrintGrid" BackgroundColor="BlueViolet" HeightRequest="100">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="A" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="B" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="C" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>

            <Image x:Name="image1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Image x:Name="image2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Image x:Name="image3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>


        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="BurlyWood">
            <Image x:Name="CapturedImage"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

The second row is images, which are picked by the user. Is it possible to take a screenshot only of the second row of GridView, and display it in the `<Image x:Name="CapturedImage"/>`. I have search how to do it, but I only came across full screen capture, which is not ideal in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create a snapshot of a specific `Xamarin.Forms.View`. You should wrap the 2nd `Grid.Row` by a single top level `View` that will contain the images as children. After that you could use platform specific capabilities to create a snapshot.

**Android**

```
public void MakeViewShot(Xamarin.Forms.View view)
{
    var nativeView = view.GetRenderer().View;
    var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled;
    nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
    nativeView.BuildDrawingCache(false);
    var bitmap = nativeView.GetDrawingCache(false);
    // TODO: Save bitmap and return filepath
    nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;
}
```

**iOS**

```
public void MakeViewShot(Xamarin.Forms.View view)
{
    var nativeView = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.GetRenderer(view).NativeView;
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(nativeView.Bounds.Size, opaque: true, scale: 0);
    nativeView.DrawViewHierarchy(nativeView.Bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true);
    var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    // TODO: Save bitmap and return filepath
}
```

Usage example:

```
<StackLayout
    x:Name="secondRow"
    Grid.Row="1">
    <Image x:Name="image1" />
    <Image x:Name="image2" />
    <Image x:Name="image3" />
</StackLayout>

MakeViewShot(secondRow);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more question: for the whole screenshot I use this this interface `Task<byte[]> CaptureAsync();`. Can I use it in this case, or should I write another interface?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Returning `byte[]` will create a copy of the image, you should either return a `Stream` or save the `Image` to disk and read it from there. However, if you really want, you could still convert `Image` to `byte[]` and return it. It is all up to your needs.

Comment: That's exactly what I want: to upload the image, but I'm not sure how to do it. The app is connected to web api. This is the code I have written: https://pastebin.com/WXtarVjh

Comment: Please consider posting a new question as it is not related to your original question. If you find my answer useful please accept it and upvote.

Comment: nativeView.GetDrawingCache(false); returns null for me. I do not display this view anywhere. I just pass new View() as parameter. Any ideas?